# How to add a row with null data in final query?

Tags: clickhouse

I have got a table with data:

```
table1
country  date       price

  USA    2001-01-25   2
  RUS    2001-01-25   17
  GER    2001-01-25   30
  USA    2001-02-25   11
  RUS    2001-02-25   22
  RUS    2001-02-26   25
```

I can get all countries with

```
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM table1;

country 
  USA 
  RUS
  GER
```

And get all prices for the month

```
SELECT sum(price), country FROM table1 WHERE date >= '2001-02-01' AND date < '2001-03-01' GROUP BY country, price;

sum(price) country
   11        USA
   47        RUS
```

But I also want to see one row for country 'GER'

```
sum(price) country
   11        USA
   47        RUS
    0        GER
```

How to do it easy in clickhouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    country,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date >= '2001-02-01' AND date < '2001-03-01'
             THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS prices
FROM table1
GROUP BY country;
```

The problem with your current `WHERE` clause is that it will filter off countries which have no matching price at all during the month of February, 2001.

If the above solution be not performant, we can writing this as a join of a table containing all countries to `table1`:

```
SELECT c.country, COALESCE(t.prices, 0) AS prices
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT country FROM table1) c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT country, SUM(prices) AS prices
    FROM table1
    WHERE date >= '2001-02-01' AND date < '2001-03-01'
    GROUP BY country
) t
    ON c.country = t.country;
```

Comment: It doesn't return row with 0

Comment: @Jens I don't know much about Clickhouse SQL, but my answer is definitely working with your sample data on SQL Server.  [See the demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b131417203adafd393f288da2d60c95b).

Comment: This has the potential to be quite expensive withing large datasets when partitioning by date.

Comment: @ecyshor I updated my answer with a join option which might run faster.  But it is not clear whether the OP actually has a dedicated table of country names.